# Escape id using this jquery row on my code

Tags: jquery, class, addclass, removeclass

Why I receive this error?

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #15/12/2015(…)
```

When I execute this?

```
jQuery('#15/12/2015').addClass('full').removeClass('empty');
```

Each row contain date as id in this format **id="dd/mm/yyyy"**

How can i resolve it by putting id in this row?

```
jQuery('#' + id).addClass('full').removeClass('empty');
```

Thanks
very much for any replies!!

M.

Comment: FYI, your [id attribute is not valid](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-id).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution 1:**

Use attribute equals selector:

```
jQuery('[id="15/12/2015"]').addClass('full').removeClass('empty');
```

you can concatenate id using:

```
jQuery('[id="' + id + '"]').addClass('full').removeClass('empty');
```

**Solution 2:**

convert `/` in id value to `\\/` to create valid id selector:

```
id = "15/12/2015"
$('#'+id.replace(/\//g, "\\/")).addClass('full').removeClass('empty');
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ns69h58j/)**